# Conditional probability with bags and balls

Tags: probability

Could someone tell me the answer of part b to the following question?

[image]

My friend and I have been arguing over what should be the answer for part b, in my case I have done

$$P(\text{required}) = P(\text{Drawing a green ball from bag one and getting one red one green})+ \ldots $$

for all three cases whilst he has simply added up each individual case without multiplying the probability of getting that type of ball from bag one. Which is the right way of going about it ?

Comment: The probability of extracting a ball from the second urn depends on those that came out in urn 1. And in urn 2 there will be 21 balls. Therefore, for the first urn there are 20 possible cases, and in urn two there are 21 possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your solution is correct, because each individual case is using the word "and" in it. Whenever we want to find the probability of event $A$ and event $B$, we end up with multiplication, because $$P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$$
If this is not clear, consider this situation graphically

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: 1]

Circles represent a collection of outcomes of the sample space $U$ that satisfy event $A$ (red circle) and $B$ (orange circle). So, $P(A)$ is how much space the red circle takes of the rectangle (for example, there are $2$ red outcomes and the rectangle has $5$ outcomes total, so $2/5$). The expression $P(B|A)$ essentially zooms in on the red circle and finds how much of the red circle does the orange area take (for example, there is $1$ orange outcome in our $2$ red outcomes, so $1/2$). If we want to find $P(A\text{ and }B)$, then graphically we want to find how much of the rectangle does the overlap of red and orange circle take. Now, if we know how much the red circle makes of rectangle and how much the overlap makes of red circle, if we multiply these things we get how much the overlap makes of the rectangle
$$\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{5}$$
The $2$s cancel out and we arrive at exactly what we needed: how much the overlap (that has $1$ outcome) makes of the rectangle (that has $5$ outcomes). Now, in our scenario we had $P(A)=2/5$ and $P(B|A)=1/2$, and as we found right now $P(A\text{ and }B)=1/5$. So, when we need to find the probability of event $A$ and event $B$, we arrive at

$$P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$$

If we do not multiply by the probability that a ball of a certain color is drawn, then this would be a completely different calculation.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for going so in-depth! Really appreciated.